# mySQL loop, put the values into an array

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following function.

```
 return $this->_blockPhoto ( $selected_screenshots, $this->aDataEntry['author_id']);
```

It requires that the variable `$selected_screenshots` is an array of values.

The problem is that I have to take the values from a mySQL look, that is reported below.

If there is only one value, everything works fine. But when there are more values in the DB, I cannot put all those values into the variable array.

In fact, since `return $this->_blockPhoto ( $selected_screenshots, $this->aDataEntry['author_id']);` is outside the mySQL loop, it gets only the first value of the loop.

So how do I store all the values from the mySQL loop into the variable? And not only the first value?

I tried to manually assign the array to the variable in the loop `$selected_screenshots = array($qryrow1['media_id']);` but it does not work and I do not think it has any sense :)

```
    $qry1="SELECT * FROM modzzz_articles_screenshots WHERE media_id='".$selected_screenshots_ID."' AND entry_id='".$this->aDataEntry['id']."'";
            $qryr1=mysql_query($qry1) or die("Error selecting: ".mysql_error());
                while($qryrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($qryr1)) {
                $selected_screenshots = array($qryrow1['media_id']);

} // END OF THE LOOK

          return $this->_blockPhoto ( $selected_screenshots, $this->aDataEntry['author_id']);
```

Can anyone give me the solution, with code? I am really confused.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code keeps overwriting `$selected_screenshots` with a new array each time. Instead, you want to *append* it:

```
$selected_screenshots = array();
while ($qryrow1 = mysql_fetch_array($qryr1)) {
    $selected_screenshots[] = $qryrow1['media_id'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save all the mysql values by looping through your results and appending them to the end of `$selected_screenshots` to do this please look below. Right now you are just assigning `$selected_screenshots` one value and neglecting the other values, so `$selected_screenshots` is having the last value that mysql returns.

This is covered http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php under the heading 'Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax'